# MVC4 Razor Looses UserID if Unbound

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, razor, model

I'm creating some user profile edit forms in MVC4 at the moment and for testing I was rendering the UserId property into a readonly textbox on the form like this:

```
<li>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserId, new { @readonly="readonly"})
</li>
```

As I'm nearing completion of the edit form I removed this textbox as it's just using up real estate.  Once I had done this the model sent back to the controller when saving had the integer default value of 0 and then the Entity Framework blows up as it cannot update any rows.  So I added this to the form:

```
<li>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId, new { @readonly="readonly"})
</li>
```

Is this a safe move?  Should I be using the ViewBag for things like this?  On the profile details page I render an edit button like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.UserId })
```

Meaning that the UserId is rendered in the link.  Is this safe and secure or do I need to rethink how I move the models and ids around the UI?

TIA,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a safe move?

This will do the job of sending the id to the server. Just get rid of the `readonly="readonly"` attribute which makes very little sense for a hidden input.

> Should I be using the ViewBag for things like this?

This doesn't change anything in terms of security. Any user could still put whatever id he wants. Whether you are using a hidden field or an ActionLink you are still sending the id as plain text to the server and anyone could forge a request and put whatever id he wants. So if you site uses some form of authentication you must absolutely check on the server side that the id that you received actually is a resource that belongs to the currently authenticated user before attempting to perform any actions on it. Otherwise some authenticated user could supply the id of a resource that belongs to another user and be able to update it. Of course that's just a hypothetical scenario, it's not clear at all if this is your case and whether this `id` needs to be secured.

Comment: Hi Darin,

The id value is part of the resource url going from the `Details(int id)` method to the `Edit(int id)` method, the problem occurred when the save button on the Edit view is clicked to  `Update(UserProfileModel userProfileModel)` method.

Since the Id was not bound to something in the Edit view it essentially vanished from the model.

Would you recommend NOT sending the Id and keeping that server side?  The more I think about it the more I lean towards making more use of the session and the `WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name)` method offered by the `WebSecurity` class.

Comment: @Jammer, as I've already stated in my answer that would depend on whether only the currently authenticated user is allowed to update resources that belong only to him. If anyone can edit any resource tat you should not worry. If only users that are owners of the resource can edit it, you could still keep the id in a hidden field but you should absolutely perform an ownership verification on the server.

Answer (score 1):

If UserId is sensitive, then there are other options

- Keep `UserId` server side only with Session state (if your architecture allows for [Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560084/session-variables-in-asp-net-mvc))
- Put it in an [encrypted cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093181/how-can-i-encrypt-a-cookie-content-in-a-simple-way-in-c-sharp-3-0). Note as per Darin, that these can be [compromised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720720/how-serious-is-this-new-asp-net-security-vulnerability-and-how-can-i-workaround).

If it isn't sensitive, then your `HiddenFor` is fine - post it back with the rest of the form.
Don't put it in your ActionLink Querystring unless this is part of your route (i.e. /Controller/Action/id)

Comment: Putting sensitive information in a cookie is a very bad approach and is not more secure than putting it in a hidden field or a query string parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest using ValueInjecter.  Here is a code snippet doing the same thing

```
[HttpGet]
    public new ActionResult Profile()
    {
        var model = new ProfileModel();

        model.InjectFrom<UnflatLoopValueInjection>(this.GetCurrentUser());

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public new ActionResult Profile(ProfileModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            this.GetCurrentUser().InjectFrom<UnflatLoopValueInjection>(model);

            try
            {
                _userService.SaveOrUpdate(this.GetCurrentUser());
                TempData["Success"] = "User was successfully updated.";
                return RedirectToAction("Profile");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Exception", "Unexpected error");
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

And here is the view...

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Profile", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Unable to update profile. Please correct the errors and try again.", new { @class = "alert alert-block alert-error" })

    @Html.EditorForModel()

    <div class="form-actions">
        <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>        
}
```

Comment: I'm already using AutoMapper for going from one object to another.  I'm not sure what problem your answer is targetting.  If the input model id is 0 it's just going to overwrite the id value in the IPrinciple, isn't it?

Comment: Are you modifying other people's profile?  Or just your own?  I don't need the ID in the view model if I am editing my own property because I already know that from the principle.